# Faster for-loop with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently testing some things with tensorflow and I built a little neural network. To train it, I'm repeatedly running the session on the optimizer object:

```
error = 0.5 * tf.square(tf.subtract(output_layer, supervised_layer))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error)

session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(1000):
    session.run([optimizer, error], feed_dict={
        input_layer: [[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]],
        supervised_layer: [[1], [1], [0], [0]]
    })
```

I feel like calling `session.run()` very often from python doesn't make good use of the way tensorflow works and probably can't use GPU processing advantages.

So my question now is quite simple: Is there any overhead on `session.run()` and is there a better way for running a session very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical scenario a single `session.run` takes up to several seconds so the cost of executing the python loop is negligible. So the short answer is that you should not worry, because you will certainly benefit from GPU acceleration when you need it. You already perform operations in batches. I would suggest to simply increase the batch size.

However, if you were absolutely certain that you need to perform multiple updates in one `session.run` call there are ways of implementing a loop in tensorflow ([tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop), [autograph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph)). So you can actually call arbitrary code multiple times within a single `session.run`. Be advised that it is quite difficult in general, but in most practical cases you could find simpler solutions, e.g. for [RNNs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent).

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem when using `sess.run()` and not using the `close()` afterwords in general case.

A session may own resources, such as `tf.Variable` and it is important to release these resources when they are no longer required. To do this, either invoke the `tf.Session.close()` method on the session, or use the session as a [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/).

The following two examples are equivalent:

```
# Using the `close()` method.
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(...)
sess.close()

# Using the context manager.
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(...)
```

On calling the `session.run()` to often...

The `Session`class is for running TensorFlow operations and the session object encapsulates the environment in which Operation objects are executed, and Tensor objects are evaluated.

If you can achieve your computations without creating the environment you can say it would be smarter to go without the `session.run()`.

Note: `Session.run()` method runs one "step" of TensorFlow computation, by running the necessary graph fragment to execute every `Operation` and evaluate every `Tensor` in `fetches`, substituting the values in `feed_dict` for the corresponding input values.

The `fetches` argument may be a single graph element, or an arbitrarily  nested list, tuple, namedtuple, dict, or OrderedDict containing graph  elements at its leaves.  A graph element can be one of the following types:

- An `tf.Operation`.   The corresponding fetched value will be `None`.
- A `tf.Tensor`.  The corresponding fetched value will be a numpy ndarray containing the
    value of that tensor.
- A `tf.SparseTensor`. The corresponding fetched value will be a `tf.SparseTensorValue`    containing the value of that sparse tensor.
- A `get_tensor_handle` op.  The corresponding fetched value will be a
    numpy ndarray containing the handle of that tensor.
- A `string` which is the name of a tensor or operation in the graph.

---

**Update**: Interactive session will not help you either. The only difference comparing to the normal `Session`, `InteractiveSession` makes itself the default session so you can call `run()` or `eval()` on variables explicitly using the session object.

```
#start the session
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# stop the session
sess.stop()
ops.reset_default_graph()
```

Comment: Wouldn't `session.close()` reset the values stored in all instances of `tf.Variable`? If so, I would lose all training progress from the last steps and that would be totally counter-productive.

Comment: Yes, `session.close()` will free all resources associated with the session.

Comment: So from what you said in your answer, I assume there is no way to run a session several times with one tensorflow function call?

Comment: Yes, as defined inside c_api.cc https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ec6df8e4fb10b25737295bcb49791842eb478400/tensorflow/c/c_api.cc#L2600